# How to use setState to update Likes in nested object array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I need to know how to write an updateState method to update the likes in this nested object array.

My state:

```
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([
    { name: 'Chelsea Hagon',
      likes: 12,  
      replyVisible: false,
      message: 'You rock at this! and a reply is visible...', 
      avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
      replys: [
        { name: 'Angela Fisher xxx', likes: 69, replyVisible: true, message: 'No! 1 Someone will team up with you! Im signed upf or the 10 and dont hav a specific partner preplaned.', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
        { name: 'Francis Watson 2', 
          likes: 13,
          replyVisible: false,
          message: 'oh man', 
          avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
          replys: [
            { name: 'Angela Fisher fuck', likes: 3, message: 'No! 2 Someone will team up with you! Im signed upf or the 10 and dont hav a specific partner preplaned.', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
            { name: 'Angela Fisher fuck', likes: 3, message: 'No! 3 Someone will team up with you! Im signed upf or the 10 and dont hav a specific partner preplaned.', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
            { name: 'Angela Fisher fuck', likes: 3, message: 'No! 2 Someone will team up with you! Im signed upf or the 10 and dont hav a specific partner preplaned.', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
            { name: 'Angela Fisher fuck', likes: 3, message: 'No! 2 Someone will team up with you! Im signed upf or the 10 and dont hav a specific partner preplaned.', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    { name: 'Angela Fisher', likes: 3, replyVisible: true, message: 'No! 400 Someone will team up with you! Im signed upf or the 10 and dont hav a specific partner preplaned.', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Carla Yates', replyVisible: true, message: 'Great work bro.', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Leslie Johnson', 
      message: 'Cant stop looking at this. dang.', 
      replyVisible: true,
      avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  
      imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506794778202-cad84cf45f1d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',
      replys: [
        { name: 'Courtney Henry', replyVisible: true, message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
        { name: 'Tom Cook', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
      ]
    },
    { name: 'Francis Watson', likes: 13, message: 'oh man', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Tracey Palmer', likes: 3, message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519244703995-f4e0f30006d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Alejandro Davidson', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517841905240-472988babdf9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Leslie Alexander', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80', imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Dries Vincent', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506794778202-cad84cf45f1d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Courtney Henry', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Michael Foster', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519244703995-f4e0f30006d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Lindsey Walton', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80', imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517841905240-472988babdf9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Tom Cook', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80'},
    { name: 'Whitney Francis', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517365830460-955ce3ccd263?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=8&w=1024&h=1024&q=80'},
    { name: 'Leonard Krasner', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519345182560-3f2917c472ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=8&w=1024&h=1024&q=80'},
    { name: 'Floyd Miles', message: 'You rock at this!', avatarURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80',  imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463453091185-61582044d556?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=8&w=1024&h=1024&q=80'},
  ]);
```

My update method:

```
  function handleAddNewLike() {
    const updateLikes = [
      comments[0],
      {likes: prevState + 1}
    ];
    setComments(updateLikes);
  }
```

I have nested comments so I think this might be complex to do... any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update the value by keeping a copy of the array..

```
function handleAddNewLike() {
    const updateLikes = [...comments];
    updateLikes[index].likes = comments[index].likes + 1;
    setComments(updateLikes);
}
```